# .bashrc and various linux startup scripts

Tags: linux, shell

On linux(eg. centos), if I need to run some start-up script, what are the various start-up places to call the script and what is each one's convention?

Comment: Starting what up?  For you when you log in via ssh?  When you log into the graphical environment?  When the system boots?  When everyone logs in?

Answer (score 2):

Vixie `cron(8)` lets you use the `@reboot` specifier to run programs at startup. This can be in your `/etc/crontab` or any user's personal `crontab(5)` file. I wouldn't recommend programmatic use of these files, leave them for the admins. (Though giving commands for admins to copy-and-paste into their `crontab(5)` is probably friendly.)

You can place startup scripts in the standard SysV init `/etc/init.d/` directory and create the matching symbolic links into `/etc/rc*.d` directories. I imagine `init(8)` has details on the scheme in place.

There is often an `/etc/rc.local` file or similar file available for system administrators to configure. I wouldn't recommend programmatic use of this file, leave it for the admins.

Depending upon how far along Centos is in converting to using [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), you can place job specifications into `/etc/init`. These look much easier to write than initscripts, but they are sadly very underdocumented at the moment.

`.bashrc` and `/etc/profile`, etc., is a complete red herring. Any shell startup scripts are for system administrator configuration or user configuration. Programmers should stay away.